# Is FieldPath supported in Flutter?

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I could not find `FieldPath` in the [`cloud_firestore` Flutter plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/cloud_firestore), however, I would assume that this is a very common tool that would be one of the first implementations for such a plugin.

[`FieldValue`](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/13905) was recently added, but I could not find anything on `FieldPath`.
If I wanted to use the `documentId` in a **query** currently, would there be a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I actually forgot about this, but I added [`FieldPath.documentId`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/FieldPath/documentId.html) as part of [a pull request](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/pull/1296) to `cloud_firestore` at some point.

This means that you can simply use it like this:

```dart
Firestore.instance.collection('movies').orderBy('rating').orderBy(FieldPath.documentId);
```

### Obsolent

<s>***`__name__`*** works if you want to *target the **document id***.</s>

You can use `'__name__'` as a `String`, which is equivalent to `FieldPath.documentId()`.

```dart
String fieldPathDocumentId = '__name__';

Firestore.instance.collection('movies').orderBy('rating').orderBy(fieldPathDocumentId);
```

Comment: could you please post any example of how to use it?

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot How can one use __name__ for instance to get documentId

Answer (score 4):

This works for me. (I am not sure this is what you wanted.)

```
Firestore.instance.collection('/collection-name')
  .where(FieldPath.documentId, isEqualTo: _someID)
  .snapshots().listen((snapshots){
    /*

    */
  });
```