# How to return Firestore documents from a list of DocumentID's in a query?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a list of DocumentID's that I want to use in a query and return data for only those documents.

The following code will return with 0 documents:

```
Future<QuerySnapshot> _getGroupsList(DocumentSnapshot data) async {
List<String> _localGroupIDs = List.from(data.data['MyGroups']);

CollectionReference colRef = Firestore.instance.collection('Groups').reference();

Query query = colRef.where('id', isEqualTo: _localGroupIDs);
QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await query.getDocuments();
return querySnapshot;
}
```

However if I remove the query and just get run getDocuments() on the collection reference I can see that all the documents are available.

I have tried to do what was suggested here, [Is FieldPath supported in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52468310/is-fieldpath-supported-in-flutter/52469844) , but it didn't seem to work for me. I was constantly getting errors.

I was also digging around here https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/cloud_firestore/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/cloudfirestore/CloudFirestorePlugin.java and I noticed that FieldPath.documentID() (on line 265) is being used but I can't see anyway to access it.

Does anyone know how to query against the DocumentID using Flutter and Firestore?

Comment: There is currently no way to retrieve a group of documents from Firestore by their IDs. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46721517/google-firestore-how-to-get-document-by-multiple-ids-in-one-round-trip

Answer (score 0):

var test =  await Firestore.instance.collection('Note').document(id).get();
try this pass the id of the document you need.

Comment: I was originally doing it by iterating over the list with a for loop and getting the ID's the way you suggested but what would be the impact of making a lot of consecutive calls to firebase instead of just one?

Code:
    `for(int i = 0; i < _localGroupIDs.length; ++i) {
      DocumentSnapshot doc = await colRef.document(_localGroupIDs[i]).get();
      _docs.add(doc);
    }`

Comment: why don't you get the collection and assign it to an array of map or something?